# How do I get XNA Game Studio 4.0?

Tags: xna, xbox360, windows

I want to get started with XNA game development, and I have bought the Pro edition of Visual Studio 2010 so I have the required software to run XNA Game Studio.

How do I get it? Is it released yet?
Is it a free download on some Microsoft site?
Do I have to pay anything? Where?

**Edit:** 
Is [this](http://create.msdn.com/en-us/resources/downloads) it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the whole XNA Game Studio 4.0 as a part of the [Windows 7 Phone Devkit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=04704acf-a63a-4f97-952c-8b51b34b00ce&displaylang=en)

(and here's the [ISO download](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=201927) if you need to install it on multiple PCs)

Answer (score 1):

Yep that's the one, just download and install it.

Answer (score 1):

For XNA 4.0 you have two different downloads. One for users in Windows XP that only includes the XNA 4.0 Framework and another for users in Vista/W7 that includes XNA 4.0 and the WP7 Dev Tools. You can get both from here:

http://create.msdn.com/en-us/resources/downloads

In the XNA Game Studio 4.0 section.